# When does the equation $f(x)=x\cdot\sqrt{2x+6}=ax$ have 2 real solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

My question is the following:

Let $f\colon[-3,\infty)\to \mathbf{R}$ with $f(x)=x\sqrt{2x+6}$.
Is there a value $a\in\mathbf{R}$ for which $f(x)=ax$ has 2 real solutions?

I tried the following:

With some caculations we find $f'(x)=\frac{3x+6}{\sqrt{2x+6}}$. Since $(0,0)$ is on the line $y=ax$, we find $f'(0)=\sqrt{6}$ and therefore a = $\sqrt{6}$.
By using the schetch of the graph I find the answer $a\in[0,\sqrt{6}$).

I feel this is kind of cheating, since I used the graph and 'cleverly guessed' the value of $a=\sqrt{6}$. Is there a more mathematical rigous way to solve this equation?

Any help is greatly valued.

Comment: The equation you have written has exactly one solution for $a\ge2\sqrt3$ and no solution for $a<2\sqrt3$, though.

Comment: Are you sure you want the domain of $f$ to be $[3,\infty)$, rather than, say, $[-3, \infty)$?  This will affect the answer.

Comment: @Jesse Madnick I made a typo, thank you for your keen eye.

Comment: When $a=4$ your equation has exactly two real solutions, namely $x=0$ and $x=5$ -- but $4\notin [0,\sqrt 6)$, so $[0,\sqrt 6)$ can't be a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

just write $x(a-\sqrt{2x+6})=0$ which means either $x=0$ or $\sqrt{2x+6}=a$. As $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed, you can find the value of $x$ for which the equality holds: $$x=\frac{a^2-6}{2}$$

Now, your $f$ is defined for $2x+6>0$, thus $x>-3$. You can understand we find a costraint for $a$ via the previous equation:

$$x=\frac{a^2-6}{2}>-3$$
Moreover, $a$ must be positive, so $a>0$. Resolve the above inequality and apply the positivity of $a$ discharge the negative solution and you will have the range of value of $a$ for which a second solution exists.

Comment: I like the first sentence here, but then it begins to look unmotivated. In most of the range you don't need to _find_ $x$ -- it's clear that $\sqrt{2x+6}=a$ has one solution when $a\ge 0$ and no solution otherwise (because the function on the left is increasing), so all we need to do is exclude the $a$ for which that one solution coincides with the $x=0$ we've already got. And that's obviously $a=\sqrt{2\cdot 0+6}$.

Comment: true. By resolving the inequality you actually find a non $0$ solution for any $a>0$. It makes sense, but it must be proven and this is the most thorugh thing I could think of.

Comment: All of the $>$ signs in this answer should be $\geq$ signs.